# How to calculate the p value between groups in rows?

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value, ggpubr

I have data as follows:

```
Name        Ratio       Group
M2.by.M1    0.993672015 High
M2.by.M1    0.600165806 High
M2.by.M1    0.393162341 High
M2.by.M1    0.101774223 High
M2.by.M1    0.214366827 High
M2.by.M1    0.096359948 High
M2.by.M1    0.413169547 High
M2.by.M1    0.024404922 High
M2.by.M1    0.192636048 High
M2.by.M1    1.334776911 Low
M2.by.M1    6.972366504 Low
M2.by.M1    3.629354996 Low
M2.by.M1    0.3838914   Low
M2.by.M1    0.551477856 Low
M2.by.M1    4.867392987 Low
M2.by.M1    0.749706358 Low
M2.by.M1    1.590161877 Low
M2.by.M1    2.285621221 No
M2.by.M1    0           No
M2.by.M1    2.614777651 No
M2.by.M1    0.25097869  No
M2.by.M1    10.59934598 No
M2.by.M1    0.315721107 No
```

I am trying to find out the significance between the groups:
I used following code:

```
library(ggpubr)
data <- read.table("ratio_m2.m1.txt",sep="\t",header = TRUE)
ggboxplot(data, x = "Group", y = "Ratio",
          width =0.5, size=0.8, 
          xlab="", ylab= "Ratio") + stat_compare_means()
```

but I am not getting any values in the output.

Comment: why would y be name instead of ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it help if you specify the comparisons you want to make? E.g.

```
library(ggpubr)
data <- read.table("ratio_m2.m1.txt", header = TRUE)

ggboxplot(data = data, x = "Group", y = "Ratio",
          width = 0.5, size = 0.8, 
          xlab = "", ylab = "Ratio") +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("High", "Low"),
                                        c("High", "No"),
                                        c("Low", "No")))
```

[image: example.png]